# How to dynamically create y axis values for ticks on victory axis?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, victory-charts

I have created a victory bar chart to show employee attrition. But y-axis of the chart is showing floating values instead of an integer but as employees' count can not be in floating point I want to show y-axis values in integer number only so the solution for the same is to define custom tick values as

```
 <VictoryAxis tickValues={[2, 4, 6, 8]}/>
```

But I don't know how I dynamically generate ticks array for my y-axis values.
Here is how my graph looks :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i was having a similar problem and struggled to find much help anywhere on this. The solution i came to was to ammend the tick using the tickFormat property of the VictoryAxis component.

```
 < VictoryAxis
     tickFormat = {(t) => (Number.isInteger(t) ? t : null)}
     dependentAxis />
```

This checks that the tick is defined as an integer and if so returns it otherwise sets the tick to be null.

Answer (score 2):

How specifically you get the values will vary depending on what your data is, but you can generally get them by grabbing a max and a min, and then getting evenly spaced values in between (or pushing the maximum up in order to do so). You can then pass the generated values to you `VictoryAxis` like this:

```
const generatedValues = // code to generate the wanted values

...

<VictoryAxis tickValues={generatedValues}>
```

Answer (score 0):

in addition to [NeuralEvolution](https://NeuralEvolution)'s answer you can use this CusomLineSegment to
not to render the grids and tick lines where they shouldnt be rendered

```
 const CustomLineSegment = (props)=>{
    // console.log(props.datum,Number.isInteger(parseFloat(props.datum)))
    if(Number.isInteger(parseFloat(props.datum)))
        return(<LineSegment {...props}/>)
    else
        return(<></>)
}
```

use it like this:

```
<VictoryAxis  dependentAxis //the y axis
        gridComponent={<CustomLineSegment/>}
        tickComponent={<CustomLineSegment/>}
        tickFormat={(t) => (Number.isInteger(t) ? Math.round(t) : null)}
        />
```